# Fix div position no matter the screen resolution is

Tags: html, css

This is my page header, it has a select menu and has to be positioned well on top of the background image, how do I fix it in position when screen resolution changes ?

Take a look

[image]

here on a bigger resolution

[image]

the html looks as follows:

```
    <div class="header">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 16px 10px 0 52px ;text-align: right; width: 230px; background: url('images/searchbar_dropdown.png') no-repeat scroll 72px 15px transparent;">
                       <select id="dept" name="dept" type="text" style="background-color: white; border: 2px solid rgb(182, 109, 49); width: 150px; height: 35px; opacity: 0;"><option></option>                                    
</select></div></td>
                        <td rowspan="2" style="width: 2px;">&nbsp;</td>

                    </tr>

            </table>
         </div>
```

and the header CSS

```
 .header {
background: url("../../images/background.png") repeat;
position: fixed;
color: white;
min-height: 65px;
padding: 5px 5px;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: A good way is using percentage instead of constant values...

Comment: @TiagoSalzmann don't be slilly now please....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The select is flowing out for you because the `fixed position`

You will need a wrapper around the box with a `position relative` and the box as `position absolute`

**Example:**

```
<div id="boxWrapper">
    <select class="selectbox">
        <option value="">option 1</option>
        <option value="">option 2</option>
        <option value="">option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

#boxWrapper {
    position: relative:
}

.selectbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is likely a combination of your `width: 100%` on the `table` and your `text-align: right` on your `td`. I suspect your `td` is not acting as you want, and not keeping its `width: 230px`, but is expanding with the screen width along with the `table`. With the `text-align: right` the `select` element is then moving also. The easiest fix would be to position the `select` such that it is `text-align: left`, unless you intend it to be right and the background to follow (in which case how you have the background attached is what you need to correct).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class="header">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 16px 10px 0px 52px; text-align: right; width: 230px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% whitesmoke; position: relative;">
                       <select style="border: 2px solid rgb(182, 109, 49); height: 35px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% yellow; opacity: 1; position: absolute; width: 150px; left: 0px;" type="text" name="dept" id="dept"><option></option>                                    
</select></td>
                        <td style="width: 2px;" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>

                    </tr>

            </tbody></table>
         </div>
```